# Angular.Copy does not allow me to create unique objects in a separate array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deep-copy

I'm building a configurator in AngularJS that uses the object **$scope.data** to allow users to edit the object via the front-end. The user can then save this object to a separate array in **$scope.builds**, allowing them to have multiple configurations. Here is the function that adds another configuration to **$scope.builds**.

```
$scope.addition = function(){
    var newData = angular.copy($scope.data);
    $scope.builds.push(newData);
}
```

Unfortunately, despite using the **angular.copy** function, all of the objects in the array of **$scope.builds** seem to be the same **$scope.data** object duplicated over and over.

EDIT:

Here is an abridged version of what **$scope.data** looks like:

```
$scope.data = [
        {
            'title': 'Select your configuration',
            'required': true,
            'options': [
                {
                    'name': 'Option 1',
                    'select': true,
                    'filter': true
                }, {
                    'name': 'Option 2',
                    'select': false,
                    'filter': true
                }, {
                    'name': 'Option 3',
                    'select': false,
                    'filter': true
                }
            ]
        }, {
            'title': 'Select your configuration',
            'required': true,
            'options': [
                {
                    'name': 'Option 1',
                    'select': true,
                    'filter': true
                }, {
                    'name': 'Option 2',
                    'select': false,
                    'filter': true
                }, {
                    'name': 'Option 3',
                    'select': false,
                    'filter': true
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

Comment: How your `$scope.data` looks like?

Comment: Provide more code, it looks like you may not be updating `$scope.data`, so you keep copying over the same object.

Comment: @codeepic at this stage I am not loading **$scope.build[i]** back into **$scope.data**, but have built a user front-end to view their previous configurations saved in **$scope.builds**. It is here that it can be seen that they are all duplicates.

Comment: @JamieMcGrory I get you, but I have a suspicion that your `angular.copy` keeps copying over the same object over and over again. You need to inspect it or `console.log` `$scope.data` just before you copy it in `addition function` but after you made the changes in the view that are supposed to change `$scope.data`. I don't think it's a problem with `angular.copy`

Comment: @codeepic I'm not 100% on what you mean. When I change the **$scope.data** object it does change that one object, and **addition()** does push that (updated and angular.copy'd) object to the **$scope.builds**. It's that it is also seemingly updating all of the other copies that are present throughout the **$scope.build** array. Have I misunderstood you here?

Comment: @codeepic you were correct. There was no issue with angular.copy. The issue was that the code which changes the configuration was being applied to the $scope.builds was from $scope.data and not from the individual $scope.builds[i], meaning they all looked the same but were actually individual copies that were functioning exactly as I needed them to. I am now off to apply for a new brain. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked for you!